# Nested loop to take input 5 times and display total and average

Tags: python

```
hoursWorked = 0
researchAssistants = 3
        
for assisstant in range(researchAssistants):
    for day in range(5):
        if day == 0:
            hoursWorked += float(input("Enter hours for research assistant {0} for Day 1: ".format(assisstant+1)))
        if day == 1:
            hoursWorked += float(input("Enter hours for research assistant {0} for Day 2: ".format(assisstant+1)))
        if day == 2:
            hoursWorked += float(input("Enter hours for research assistant {0} for Day 3: ".format(assisstant+1)))
        if day == 3:
            hoursWorked += float(input("Enter hours for research assistant {0} for Day 4: ".format(assisstant+1)))
        if day == 4:
            hoursWorked += float(input("Enter hours for research assistant {0} for Day 5: ".format(assisstant+1)))
    print()
    print("Research assistant {0} worked in total".format(assisstant+1), hoursWorked, "hours")
    avgHoursWorked = hoursWorked / 5
    if avgHoursWorked > 6:
        print("Research assistant {0} has an average number of hours per day above 6".format(assisstant+1) )
    print()
```

I want the code to take amount of hours worked per day in a 5-day work week for three employees. I then want it to summarize it to hours/week for each employee. If an employee's average number of hours per day is above 6, the program should flag this.

So far I the program takes the input, and gives the total. But the average is wrong. I believe `avgHoursWorked` should be in the nested for loop - but this does not really work for me. I would rather want the input to be taken first, then display the totals and flag an avg. >6 at the end.

**Edit:** 
Here is the output as per above code.

```
Enter hours for research assistant 1 for Day 1: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 1 for Day 2: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 1 for Day 3: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 1 for Day 4: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 1 for Day 5: 5

Research assistant 1 worked in total 25.0 hours 

Enter hours for research assistant 2 for Day 1: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 2 for Day 2: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 2 for Day 3: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 2 for Day 4: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 2 for Day 5: 5

Research assistant 2 worked in total 50.0 hours
Research assistant 2 has an average number of hours per day above 6

Enter hours for research assistant 3 for Day 1: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 3 for Day 2: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 3 for Day 3: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 3 for Day 4: 5
Enter hours for research assistant 3 for Day 5: 5

Research assistant 3 worked in total 75.0 hours
Research assistant 3 has an average number of hours per day above 6
```

In this case, the hours worked are being added-up where they should really be per individual Research Assistant

Comment: How do you know that `"the average is wrong"`? Can you update your question with the text of a session where it goes wrong and what the right output should be?

Comment: If I add say 5 hours per day in the first iteration, it will not call the if statement because avg. is <6. But it will keep `avgHoursWorked` at 25 and then for the second iteration, add whatever to that and divide it by 5.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for your comment, I added an output edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you meant to reset `hoursWorked` for each assistant:

```py
researchAssistants = 3
        
for assisstant in range(researchAssistants):
    hoursWorked = 0
    for day in range(5):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you! It is the second time today I am missing to bring the variable into the loop.